# UILabel have to fit size with out break in middle of the word

Tags: iphone, uilabel

I created a UILabel dynamically and i will update the data in to that dynamically.

Am getting output with many number of lines and it is fine 
my problem is word break in middle to the next line although i use line break mode word wrap

Help me out of this am googling it from 5hours.

The data passed to that UILabel is orthogonist,endonist,psychologist,cardioligist

```
CGSize constraint8 = CGSizeMake(190, 2000.0f);
CGSize size8=[temp sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14] constrainedToSize:constraint8 lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
specialities1 =[[UILabel alloc]init];
[specialities1 setFrame:CGRectMake(124,218,190, size8.height)];
specialities1.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentLeft;
specialities1.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
specialities1.numberOfLines=0;
specialities1.lineBreakMode=UILineBreakModeClip;
specialities1.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14];
specialities1.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",temp ];
[specialities1 sizeToFit];
[testscroll addSubview:specialities1];
```

Comment: `specialities1.numberOfLines=0;` really?

Comment: ya so that for large text we get maximum number of lines

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
specialities1.lineBreakMode=UILineBreakModeClip;
```

to :

```
specialities1.lineBreakMode= UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
```

Comment: @user1986984 : Can you comment specialities1.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentLeft; and [specialities1 sizeToFit]; and check?

Comment: I tried what you said,am getting that long text in single line i cant visualize half of the data

Comment: @user1986984 : Can you post the screenshot of your screens?

Answer (score 0):

Change both this line in your code.

According to your code above you are setting 0 lines in your label. So change it to,

```
specialities1.numberOfLines=size8.height/12;//(=1000, or whatever according to your requirement)
specialities1.lineBreakMode= UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
```

**Source**

**Get size**

```
NSString *text = [dicOtherInfo  objectForKey:@"msg"];
CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(200, 1000.0f);
CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:12] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

**Set Size**

```
UILabel *lblMsg=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,15, size.width, size.height)];
[lblMsg setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
lblMsg.text = text;
lblMsg.numberOfLines = (size.height/16);
lblMsg.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentLeft;
lblMsg.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
lblMsg.textColor=[UIColor redColor];
[lblMsg setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:12]];
```

Comment: I tried what you said,am getting that long text in single line i cant visualize half of the data

Comment: you have to make number of line more then 0, depending on your text height and width..

Comment: It is not a static data to set numbers of lines

Comment: thats why i mention than size8.height/12 , so you can make this 12 according to your requirement... in my case, for [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:12], i was using lblMsg.numberOfLines = (size.height/16);

Comment: I tried that but am getting total data in single line.i cant visualise the text totally

Comment: ya your code works fine.But my problem does not solve using your code.

Comment: as it is a long text Using lblMsg.numberOfLines = (size.height/16); getting data in single line i cant see the total data on simulator

Comment: this in not the problem of code.... your code working fine at my end , make some other sample project and implement my code...and then let me  know

Comment: I dont have problem with number of lines .Both your code and my code is same except that setnumberoflines but it is not useful to me.when jumping to the next line am getting break of the word please tell me solution to that

Comment: break of word mean., can you please upload screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Try my below method:

```
-(float) calculateHeightOfTextFromWidth:(NSString*) text: (UIFont*)withFont: (float)width :(UILineBreakMode)lineBreakMode
{
[text retain];
[withFont retain];
CGSize suggestedSize = [text sizeWithFont:withFont constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(width, FLT_MAX) lineBreakMode:lineBreakMode];

[text release];
[withFont release];

return suggestedSize.height;
}
```

and use it like below:

```
    UILabel *lblAddress = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    [lblAddress setFrame:CGRectMake(110, 31, 200, 50)];        
    lblAddress.text = @"your Text ";
    lblAddress.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    lblAddress.numberOfLines = 0;
    lblAddress.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12];

    lblAddress.frame = CGRectMake(lblAddress.frame.origin.x, lblAddress.frame.origin.y, 
                             200,[self calculateHeightOfTextFromWidth:lblAddress.text :lblAddress.font :200 :UILineBreakModeWordWrap] ); 

    lblAddress.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

    [self.view addSubview:lblAddress];
```